# Echo returns the number instead of a string

Tags: php, sql, echo, rounding

Why echo provides `16` instead of a SQL query `UPDATE...`?

```
for ($i=0;...) {
    $lat = round(($deg + $min/60 + $sec/3600),6);

    $query = "UPDATE `Parking` 
              SET lat=" . $lat . " 
              WHERE id = " . $i+16 . "";
    $result=ejecutar_query($query);
    echo $query;
}
```

Comment: @raina77ow: ejecutar_query is not important here,because the problem was with $query. It was equal to 16 instead of a normal query sentence. The answer of Matei Mihai solved this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
 $query = "UPDATE `Parking` 
           SET lat=" . $lat . " 
           WHERE id = " . ($i+16);
 $result=ejecutar_query($query);
 echo $query;
```

Is this ok?

Answer (score 2):

The correct code is ( check:($i+16) ):

```
for ($i=0;...) {
    $lat = round(($deg + $min/60 + $sec/3600),6);

    $query = "UPDATE `Parking` 
              SET lat=" . $lat . " 
              WHERE id = " . ($i+16) . "";
    $result=ejecutar_query($query);
    echo $query;
}
```

Because PHP is not hardly typed language the + operator converts everything to int.